# Query and insert data into a MySQL table at the same time using a Python script

Tags: python, mysql, scripting

I have a python script which query's the database and display the result.I want to store these results in a MySQL table also. How can I modify my script to query the database as well as store the results in a table?

## myscript.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Template, Context
import MySQLdb
import sys
from tabulate import tabulate
from prettytable import PrettyTable

class license(object):
   def __init__(self, arg):
    super(license, self).__init__()
    self.arg = arg

connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd =    "root", db = "edxapp1")
cursor = connection.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("""select   shoppingcart_registrationcoderedemption.redeemed_by_id,auth_userprofile.name,auth_user.email,shoppingcart_registrationcoderedemption.registration_code_id,shoppingcart_courseregistrationcode.code,shoppingcart_courseregistrationcode.invoice_id
            from shoppingcart_registrationcoderedemption inner join 
            shoppingcart_courseregistrationcode 
            on shoppingcart_registrationcoderedemption.registration_code_id = shoppingcart_courseregistrationcode.id
            inner join auth_userprofile on shoppingcart_registrationcoderedemption.redeemed_by_id=auth_userprofile.user_id
            inner join auth_user on auth_user.id=auth_userprofile.user_id order by redeemed_by_id""")

data = cursor.fetchall ()
t = PrettyTable(['USER ID','NAME', 'EMAIL', 'LICENSE ID', 'CODE', 'INVOICE ID'])
for row in data :
    t.add_row([row[0] , row[1] , row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]])       
print t

cursor.close ()
```

## My result is:

[image: results]

Thank you!

Comment: Hm, create the table say atable once? Wouldn't then INSERT INTO atable SELECT ... work for you? Or do you have to process the data returned from the select in your python script before inserting?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Dilettant I just want to store my results in another table, I don't want to do any processing.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to check a pure SQL based solution along the lines of the INSERT INTO atable SELECT ... proposed in my previous comment. This also helps on large data sets, as the volume does not go over the wire into your python application memory, but remains in the mysql db server.